# Node JS - Youtube API Is Blank

Tags: javascript, node.js, youtube, youtube-data-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I downloaded and installed the google apis with `npm install googleapis` and now i'm trying to access the api in my node js file with this code:

```
var google = require('googleapis')
var youtube = google.youtube({version: 'v3', auth: API_KEY})
```

However, when I try to access the videos object, I always get back `null`. Apparently, the youtube object is corrupted because when I stringify it I get this back:

```
{"_options":{"auth":"*********"},"activities":{},"captions":{},"channelBanners":{},"channelSections":{},"channels":{},"commentThreads":{},"comments":{},"guideCategories":{},"i18nLanguages":{},"i18nRegions":{},"liveBroadcasts":{},"liveStreams":{},"playlistItems":{},"playlists":{},"search":{},"subscriptions":{},"thumbnails":{},"videoAbuseReportReasons":{},"videoCategories":{},"videos":{},"watermarks":{},"google":{"_options":{},"auth":{"_cachedCredential":null}}}
```

So all of the little "subobjects" are empty. How do I fix this?

Comment: Update: all of the api's are empty in this manner. I tried `urlshortener` and the same problem persisted.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if the dependency is listed in your package.json file ? If not try npm install --save googleapis which directly adds it to your dependency list

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing worrying in the fact that your `youtube` variable shows empty objects when stringified, because JSON representation of that object only contains properties that are primitive types. `youtube.videos` object contains only methods, which are ommited by `JSON.stringify`.

Try this:

```
var google = require('googleapis');
var youtube = google.youtube({version: 'v3', auth: API_KEY});
var queryOptions = {
    'part': 'id,snippet',
    'maxResults': 5,
    'id': 'dQw4w9WgXcQ,HL1UzIK-flA'
};
youtube.videos.list(queryOptions, function(err, data) {
    if(err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }

    console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score -2):

For youtube api I use youtube-node and it works fine: https://github.com/nodenica/youtube-node